# Maven-Tycho Eclipse: Error installing plug-in built by Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, build-automation, tycho

I am newbie to automating your build using Maven-Tycho. I followed the instructions on this site
http://zeroturnaround.com/blog/building-eclipse-plug-ins-with-maven-3-and-tycho/ and did the following

1. I downloaded the zip file with poms,extracted it and did a `mvn clean install`. It said "BUILD SUCCESS".
2. I went into the -> achievements\update-site\target folder and then zipped the site folder and tried to install it as a plugin, this is giving me a error saying no software site found at jar file... the zip file has the features, plugin folders, content.jar, artifacts.jar and the site.xml files...

Wonder what is wrong... Could you please help me with this...

I am using Maven 3.0.4 with Eclipse Version: Helios Service Release 1

Comment: "tried to install it as a plugin, this is giving me a error saying no software site found at jar file" - @Abbas: please clarify what exactly you did here

Answer (score 2):

In an `eclipse-update-site` packaging type, the folder `target/site` is a p2 repository; in an `eclipse-repository` packaging type, the p2 repository is in `target/repository`.

You can install from these folder by adding them as a "local" software site in Eclipse.